# Merge sort when i insert (> 2000000 ) ,it will show "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". But i already use the dynamic array

Tags: c

Merge sort when i insert (> 2000000 ) ,it will show "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

When I try to build a very large array of random numbers, it’s okay, but I can’t build a large array with merge sort.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 

void merge(long *arr, long  l, long  m, long r) { 
    long i, j, k; 
    long n1 = m - l + 1; 
    long n2 = r - m; 

    /* create temp arrays */
    int  L[n1], R[n2]; 

    /* Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] */

    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) 
        L[i] = arr[l + i]; 

    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) 
        R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j]; 
    /* Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r]*/
    i = 0; // Initial index of first subarray 
    j = 0; // Initial index of second subarray 
    k = l; // Initial index of merged subarray 
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) { 
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) { 
            arr[k] = L[i]; 
            i++; 
        } 
        else { 
            arr[k] = R[j]; 
            j++; 
        } 
        k++; 
    } 

    /* Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there 
       are any */
    while (i < n1) { 
        arr[k] = L[i]; 
        i++; 
        k++; 
    } 

    /* Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there 
       are any */
    while (j < n2) { 
        arr[k] = R[j]; 
        j++; 
        k++; 
    } 
} 

void mergeSort(long *arr, long l, long r) { 
    if (l < r) { 
        // Same as (l+r)/2, but avoids overflow for 
        // large l and h 
        long m = l + (r - l) / 2; 

        // Sort first and second halves 
        mergeSort(arr, l, m); 
        mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r); 

        merge(arr, l, m, r); 
    } 
} 


int main(int argc,char **argv){
    srand(time(0));
    long n=2<<16;
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    long *arr=malloc(sizeof(long )*n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        arr[i]=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i]=(rand()%1000);
    //for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        //printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    mergeSort(arr, 0, n - 1); 
    free(arr);
    printf("OK");
    printf("\n");
}
```

Let the program run without Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I used Ubuntu linux to compile:

```
gcc merge.c -o merge

./merge 10000000 //not ok**
```

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Are you sure you're not accessing that array out of bounds?

Comment: At `/* Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] */`, why are you iterating instead of using `memcpy`? Similarly, `for(int i=0;i<n;i++) arr[i]=0;` can be replaced by a single call to `memset`.

Comment: What size are `L[n1]` and `R[n2]`? If large, they probably shouldn't be on the stack.

Comment: `int  L[n1], R[n2];`  VLAs.  If these are on the stack (not sure), then you probably are blowing the stack up.  Consider using proper dynamic memory allocation procedures to make sure these are allocated on the heap.

Comment: More than VLAs, you are dealing with hundreds of thousands of calls in the recursive function.

Comment: I agree with @RobertoCaboni the depth of recursion is very high plus the big objet `L` `R` your stack is too small, you can increase it or redesign your recursion and use dynamic allocation (and test malloc result)

Comment: @RobertoCaboni - thought about that, but if each section is indeed a half, the stack size would only be log2(size) - so less than 20, maybe 30 if we approached a 32-bit int.  If the data became unbalanced though, boom.  And the compiler may save his butt if it is able to convert it to iteration.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan you are right. Not only I overestimated the depth, but I forgot that branches are executed sequentially. Each `mergeSort` call takes 8+4+4+8+returnAddress bytes. So `merge` vla arrays might become dominant.

Comment: for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) L[i] = arr[l + i]; how to change to memcpy?